# How to run shell script in background while start On CentOS?

Tags: shell, reboot

I have a shell script contain loop like this:

```
while true
do
  if ... ; then
    ...
  else
    ...
    break
  fi
done
```

I want this script to run backend while OS start. I have try to add this script into /etc/rc.d/local.rc as startup script. But OS start too long, and after OS start up, this script did not exist.

So how to add this script into backend while OS start up? And I need this script also could be start up by hand in backend. Thank you~

Comment: I believe that the word you are looking for is “background”.

Answer (score 3):

To run a script on startup, you should start it from

```
/etc/cron.d/myrebootscript
```

with the content

```
@reboot <user> <command>
```

example:

```
@reboot joe /usr/local/bin/myscript
```

The script will be executed at an unpredictable time during startup. If for instance the script should wait for the network to be started, a loop should be added to `/usr/local/bin/myscript`:

```
#! /bin/bash
# wait for 10.1.2.3 is pong'ing
while ! ping -c1 -W1 10.1.2.3 > /dev/null ; do
  sleep 1
done
do_my_command_here
```

`/etc/rc.local` is deprecated nowadays.

Comment: When does cron run the script? After all the services or while? Because OP wanted the script to run while the OS start's up. +1 for the answer though, I love this `cron` option.

Comment: Just how "unpredictable" is the timing?  Also, how can it decide whether or not to wait for the network?

Comment: To find out about the timing, put a line in your script with `/usr/bin/logger My script startet` and look for that message in `/var/log/syslog` afterwards.
To avoid waiting for the network just skip the `while` block.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson The cron script will start after the cron service has started.

Answer (score 0):

Include the script in /etc/rc.d/rc.local file so it will execute once all init scripts are executed.

Another option we can add path in .bash_profile